# How can I get the longest word and it's length from a dictionary along with the most common word?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a text file which is as follows:

```
['To be or not to be,',
 'that is the question.']
```

I populated the text into a dictionary called hamlet_dict so the key is the word and the value is the number of times it appears in the text. I am trying to write a code so I can get the longest word in the dictionary as well as the length of the longest word. I also want the most common word as well as the count of the most common word.

I created a variable and a list to use for the longest word.

```
length = 0
longest = []

for k in hamlet_dict.keys(): 
    if (len(k) > length):
        length = len(k)
```

I want to append the length of the longest word to the list longest. This is the starting point but I don't know where to go from here.

```
for k in hamlet_dict.keys():
```

Finally, I want to print the statement
print(f'There are {length} characters in the longest word. The word is {longest}.')

So the output should be:

```
There are 8 characters in the longest word. The word is question.
```

But I am getting:

There are 8 characters in the longest word. The word is [].

I have a similar problem with the most common word and the count of the most common word.

I have a variable and a list:

```
common = []
count = 0
```

For the count, I have:

```
for i in hamlet_dict.values():
    if i > count:
        count = i
```

How can I add the matching words of the variable to the list?

I want to print:

print(f'{common} is the most common word(s). It showed up {count} times.')

The output I am getting is:

[] is the most common word(s). It showed up 2 times.

But I want:

```
to, be is the most common word(s). It showed up 2 times.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you never add anything to `longest`. Why is it a list, do you want all the words that are that length?

Comment: If you want to get the most common word, use `collections.Counter()`. It has a built-in method to get the most common.

Comment: For the first part: `longest_word = max(hamlet_dict, key=len)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. The list of lines is combined into a single space-delimited string so the total counts include all of the text. You can just as easily have it provide separate values for each line if you want.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation


lines = ['To be or not to be,', 'that is the question.']
# combine the lines into a single space-delimited string
line = ' '.join(lines)

# get words in each line & make them lowercase for case-insensitivity
words = line.lower().split()
# remove punctuation from words list (e.g. otherwise "be," counts as a word)
words = [
    word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)) for word in words
]

# get the longest words and their length
longest_words = [w for w in words if len(w) == len(max(words, key=len))]
length = len(longest_words[0])

# get counts of each word in the line
counts = Counter(words).most_common()
# get a list of the words that appear the most
# (index [0] in counts is the word, index [1] is the count)
result = [w for w in counts if w[1] == max(counts)[1]]

# show the results
print(f'There are {length} characters in the longest word(s): '
      f'{longest_words}')
print(f'The most common word(s) is/are: {result}')
# => There are 8 characters in the longest word(s): ['question'].
# => The most common word(s) is/are: [('to', 2), ('be', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to get the counts of the common words without importing any additional modules. I am trying to do everything via standard python functions. The code I have gives me the count of the most common words which is 2. Now, I am trying to figure out how to get the common words themselves returned. If you have any pointers, it would be appreciated!

Comment: The words themselves are returned in `result`, which is a list of tuples, e.g. `('to', 2)`. The first element in each tuple is the word, the second is the count (which is a bit repetitive, as it will be the same for each of the "most common" words. Also, `collections.Counter` is part of the standard library and therefore *is* a "standard Python function" (the same goes for `string.punctuation`, for that matter). There's no value in limiting yourself unduly and forcing yourself to reinvent wheels Python already has - it's better to use the right tool(s) for the job.